# SQL Server 2005: Importing data from SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

In SQL Server 2000, you have the "All Tasks... - Export Data" option.  Where is this option the SQL Server 2005 Management Studio?

Or, is there a SQL Server 2005 way of doing this?

EDIT:  I am using the Express edition.

EDIT:  Joel's response answers my question but Mike's answer gives a great alternative to those of us using the Express edition (vote him up!!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the express edition of management studio the Import and Export features aren't available.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the excellent SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en

It allows you to generate a script which contains data, schema, or both.  The script can be targeted towards SQL 2000 or SQL 2005.

Some use it for web hosting environments.  I use it to move data when I have no other option.

Answer (score 1):

DTS has been replaced by SSIS on the business intelligence end of things.

Comment: No, sorry I responded before you mentioned you were using express.

Comment: "DTS has been replaced by SSIS on the business intelligence end of things."  ---  and his is quite unfortunate for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest to just do a backup in SQL 2000 and then import the backup into SQL 2005 using the restore. Those options are available in the Express Edition.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the BCP option.