# Tools to generate SQL DDL and Content from an existing database

Tags: sql-server, ddl

Does anyone know of a reasonably priced tool that will create DDL statements to create a SQL Server database *and* appropriate Insert statements to recreate the data?  I use the Red Gate tools to do database compares (including content compares) and this comes close (I could always compare with an empty schema) but I was wondering if there was a tool that others found useful that did this in one step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at [SQL Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en)? It will create all the DDL statements you require for all database elements (tables, views, SPs, users etc).

If you're using SQL 2008, it comes built into the management studio. [More info on 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2007/10/15/sql-database-publishing-wizard-is-now-in-visual-studio-orcas.aspx).

Comment: Non Express versions of the manager have been able to since SQL2000 ;)

Answer (score 4):

Late answer... hopefully someone will find it useful…

There is a tool from Red Gate called SQL Multi Script that can do scripting for what you need. Not sure if it existed when the question was asked though :)

Another good piece is [SQL build tool from ApexSQL](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_build.aspx) which can also do all kind of insert and other scripts…

Disclaimer: I’m not affiliated with any of the companies mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en)

Saw [Austin Solonen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378559/import-existing-stored-procedures-in-sql-server#378578) post this tool in a somewhat related thread. Express editions appearantly don't hove Import and Export.

Comment: Thank you, this deserves the "answer" flag as well!

Answer (score 2):

The **[database publishing wizard](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2007/10/15/sql-database-publishing-wizard-is-now-in-visual-studio-orcas.aspx)** that is included in Visual Studio 2008 performs this function.

It is also available [via CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/sqlhost/) as an add-on for prior versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Wow, step away mid-response to go to the bathroom and look how badly you get beaten!

Comment: Thanks anyway Portman.  It does seem like answers fly quickly on SO.  Good  answer though...I voted you up for being right anyway.